# Не могу запустить Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, debian, intellij-idea

При запуске Intellij IDEA на Debian 8.3 выдаёт сообщение

> `tools.jar` seems to be not in IDEA classpath.
>  Please ensure JAVA_HOME
>   points to JDK rather than JRE

**upd:**

Похоже, что отсутствует переменная окружения JAVA_HOME, но как ее прописать так, чтобы она была видна всей системе и сохранялась после перезагрузки?

Comment: Написано же: убедитесь, что переменная окружения JAVA_HOME указывает на JDK, а не на JRE. Вот и проверьте её.

Comment: А не подскажете, как это сделать? Если бы знал - не задавал бы вопроса.

Comment: `$ echo $JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Выдает пустую строку. Если я выполняю команду `export JAVA_HOME=path_to_JDK` то переменная окружения добавляется, но похоже, что видна она только в сеансе терминала. После перезапуска терминала она уже не видна.

Comment: попробуйте присвоить переменной нужное значение, а затем там же запустить программу.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin пробовал. безрезультатно.

Comment: а какой-нибудь jdk у вас установлен и какое именно значение вы присваивали переменной окружения JAVA_HOME? если не установлен, то установите, как написано по ссылке из ответа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый мощный способ прописать переменную `JAVA_HOME`, это добавить ее в файл /etc/profile:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/my/opt/jdk8
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Вообще, существует множество мест, куда еще можно прописать переменные окружения, с возможными расположениями для вашего дистрибутива лучше всего ознакомиться в документации на дистрибутив. Плюс использования `/etc/profile` перед, например, `~/.bashrc`, в том, что после перезагрузки эта переменная будет доступна всем пользователям, в т.ч. root, что полезно когда вы занимаетесь веб-разработкой.

Изменения в `/etc/profile` проще всего применить с помощью простой перезагрузки, тогда их подхватят все системные сервисы. В мире GNU\Linux это звучит как опасная ересь, но для десктопа это действительно проще всего.

К сожалению, иногда простое прописывание `JAVA_HOME` не решает всех проблем. Например, некоторые утилиты и сервисы проводят хитрые манипуляции с login shell, кому-то (н-р sysvinit initscripts) приходится запускаться вообще без login shell, и так далее. Тогда можно попробовать установить системную джаву из PPA или откуда-нибудь еще. Вот пример для Debian:

```
echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list
echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys EEA14886
apt-get update
apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Тут читатель воскликнет, что устанавливать на Debian что-то из PPA Ubuntu - жуткая ересь, но опять же это самое простое для десктопа.

Критерием того, что все манипуляции проведены правильно, будет правильный вывод команды `java -version` в терминале, и корректный путь к JDK в результате выполнения `echo $JAVA_HOME`. Проверьте, что вывод корректен не только из-под текущего пользователя, но от root.

Answer (score 1):

мой вариант изначальной установки

я распаковываю архив с jdk в /opt/jdk далее

> apt-get purge openjdk-*
>
> echo "JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk" >> /etc/profile
>
> echo "PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin" >> /etc/profile
>
> echo "JRE_HOME=/opt/jdk/jre" >> /etc/profile
>
> echo "PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin" >> /etc/profile
>
> echo "export JAVA_HOME" >> /etc/profile echo "export JRE_HOME" >> /etc/profile
>
> echo "export PATH" >> /etc/profile
>
> update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java"
> "/opt/jdk/bin/java" 1
>
> update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/opt/jdk/bin/javac" 1
>
> update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/opt/jdk/bin/javaws" 1
>
> update-alternatives --set java /opt/jdk/bin/java
>
> update-alternatives --set javac /opt/jdk/bin/javac
>
> update-alternatives --set javaws /opt/jdk/bin/javaws